# Blurring background without restructuring html?

Tags: html, css, filter, blur

I am trying to apply a CSS blur property to a wrapper div, but don't want to affect my text. With the framework I am using it will be fairly difficult to restructure the html. Is there a way to only blue the background and not text?

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
background-color:red;
}
```

If anyone could point me into the direction of a solution, if there is one, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps worth noting that you can't actually blur *backgrounds*...only elements.

So, a pseudo-element would be the answer here.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.wrapper:before` and style its background instead of `.wrapper`.
This [codepen](http://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB) by [Matthew Wilcoxson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266375/matthew-wilcoxson) might help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes...also I just answered to that effect....but you can't blur backgrounds...only elements.

Comment: Yup you're right. I am in a little bit of a rush right now. I'll edit it later.

Comment: You can do so but you're only repeating what I've already answered...It's up to you.